# Parse multiline json log with logstash

Tags: asp.net, json, logstash, elk

I need to parse a multi-line json log with exceptions and stacktraces using logstash.
I have asp.net core log generated with NLog in json format:

```
{ "timestamp": "2021-01-31T17:18:30.1781670+03:00", "level": "Error", "eventid": "0", "logger": "WebScraper.WebApi.Controllers.ProductWatcherController", "callsite": "ProductWatcherController.CreateProduct", "message": "Internal server error", "exception": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The connection is not established, because the destination computer rejected the connection request.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): The connection is not established. the destination computer rejected the connection request.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at WebScraper.Core.Helpers.HangfireSchedulerClient.CreateOrUpdateScheduler(ProductSchedulerDto productSchedulerDto) in D:\C#\WebScraper\WebScraper.Core\Helpers\HangfireSchedulerClient.cs:line 43
   at WebScraper.Core.ProductWatcherManager.CreateProduct(String productUrl, Site siteDto, List`1 scheduler, Boolean pushToHangfire) in D:\C#\WebScraper\WebScraper.Core\ProductWatcherManager.cs:line 131
   at WebScraper.WebApi.Controllers.ProductWatcherController.CreateProduct(CreateProductDto createProductDto) in D:\C#\WebScraper\WebScraper.WebApi\Controllers\ProductWatcherController.cs:line 202", "url": "https:\/\/localhost\/api\/ProductWatcher\/product", "action": "CreateProduct" }
```

I am currently testing this logstash.conf

```
input {
        file {
                codec => multiline
                {
                    pattern => '^{'
                    negate => true
                    what => previous                
                }
                start_position => "beginning"
                path => "/usr/data/json-log.txt"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}

filter {
        mutate {
            gsub => [ 'message','\n','']
        }
        json {
                source => "message"
        }
}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
                index => "file-json"
        }

        stdout {}
}
```

Please help to make the correct config.

Comment: What issue are you having with what that configuration does?

Comment: @Badger In elastic I get the tags `multiline, _jsonparsefailure` and whole json fits into the section `message`. In this section json not parsed.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON parser is objecting to "D:\C#\WebScraper\WebScraper.Core", because \C is not a valid escape. In your logstash log you should be seeing

```
:exception=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unrecognized character escape 'C' (code 67)
```

I suggest you modify the message to replace backslash with forward slash. You could do that using

```
mutate { gsub => [ 'message', '[\\]', '/'] }
```

Note that you cannot have backslash preceding a quote, since it gets treated as an escape, so you have to use a character group containing backslash. That also means you cannot easily convert the `\` to `\\`, which would be the other way to fix it.